# How to parse JsonObject to List<MyClass> using gson

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I need a list of objects and I'm having problems to get it. I'm pretty new using this so someone who can help me?

I'm using volley to get a jsonObject and then I need convert it(I saw the best wa to do this is with gson).  Below you can see how looks an example of my json.

```
{
network: {
    company: "JCDecaux",
    href: "/v2/networks/dublinbikes",
    id: "dublinbikes",
    location: {
        city: "Dublin",
        country: "IE",
        latitude: 53.3498053,
        longitude: -6.2603097
    },
    name: "dublinbikes",
    stations: [
        {
            empty_slots: 37,
            extra: {
                address: "Fitzwilliam Square East",
                bonus: false,
                connected: "1",
                last_update: "1434047944",
                open: true,
                slots: 40,
                ticket: true,
                uid: 89
            },
            free_bikes: 3,
            id: "153ff4dfb7bd8912ef91c10849129c2e",
            latitude: 53.335211,
            longitude: -6.2509,
            name: "Fitzwilliam Square East",
            timestamp: "2015-06-11T18:41:31.11Z"
        },
        {
            empty_slots: 0,
            extra: {
                address: "Portobello Harbour",
                bonus: false,
                connected: "1",
                last_update: "1434047764",
                open: true,
                slots: 30,
                ticket: false,
                uid: 34
            },
            free_bikes: 30,
            id: "3c0cfd547a142bb651280991a412bcbe",
            latitude: 53.330362,
            longitude: -6.265163,
            name: "Portobello Harbour",
            timestamp: "2015-06-11T18:41:31.15Z"
        },
```

... ect

Station class

```
public class Station {
    public Station(){}

    public String StationName;
    public String Distance;
    public String Slots;
    public String Bikes;
    public String LastUpdate;

    //Getters and Setters ...
}
```

Below you can see what I have done so far..

```
 //stations
 JSONObject jsonNetwork = new JSONObject(response.getString("network"));

   Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {
                }.getType();
   List<Station> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonNetwork, listType);
```

But I don't know how to parse all this and avoid the data I dont need and also the function `Gson().fromJson` needs and JsonArray and what I have is a `JsonObject`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think I'm totally wrong using gson and I have no idea how to parse it.

Comment: You need to create the classes for objects in order to parse the main object itself into a class.

Comment: mmm and there is not a way to avoid the data I don't need? @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that you are looking for are the stations then I think you should do the following:

```
//stations
    JSONObject jsonNetwork = new JSONObject(response.getString("network"));
    JSONArray stationsArray = jsonNetwork.getJSONArray("stations");
```

Now, you should pass this stationsArray variable to the **fromJson** method. Also, the variable names of your Station class should be equal to the key names that you want to extract from your json. There is a good example in the following link:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourClass obj = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), YourClass.class);
```

Comment: What I need is a List of my objects(Myclass) and also how can I get the jsonString and what I have is a JsonObject and doesnt work myJsonObject.toString() @spgodara

Comment: `YourClass[] obj = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), YourClass[].class);`

Comment: You can use `response.getString("network")`, which is a `String`. Also create classes implementing `Serializable` for each level required.

Comment: ``response.getString("network")`` is working properly but when I execute ``Station[] obj = gson.fromJson(temp, Station[].class);`` fails and I think the problem is how looks my Station class.. so what should looks my Station class. I have added my class here(http://jsfiddle.net/dz254cy8/1/) to show you how looks and also the jsonString  @spgodara

Comment: Implement `Serializable` interface in `Station` class